# STRCAT Code builds, runs but crashes out

Tags: pointers, strcat

I am running through some basic tutorials on C, using `Code::Blocks`.

Can anyone help me out with the following code, with some explanation? It builds but crashes when run.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LEN 40

main()
{
   int pos;
   char *line,*aster,*blank;

   line=(char *)malloc(MAX_LEN);
   aster=(char *)malloc(1);
   blank=(char *)malloc(1);
   line="                                        ";
   aster="*";
   blank="";

   printf("Enter position of star (1-40): ");
   scanf("%d",&pos);

   if(pos>0&&pos<41)
   {
       printf("\n");
       printf("         1         2         3         4\n");
       printf("1234567890123456789012345678901234567890\n");
       puts(strcat(strncat(blank,line,pos-1),aster));
   }
   else
    printf("Out of range");
}
```

The problem seems to lie within the strcat line of code and I guess the use of pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `blank` field provides space for one character, but you need up to 40 characters there. When using `strcat` or `strncat`, the destination buffer (which is the first argument to either function) must provide enough space for the concatenated string and a terminating `\0` character.

What you want to do is something like

```
line = "                                        ";
blank = malloc(MAX_LEN+1); /* 40 characters + terminating '\0' */
blank[0] = 0; /* Needed for strcat to work */
[...]
puts(strcat(strncat(blank, line, pos-1), aster));
```

Another note: Your use of `line` and `aster` leads to a memory leak. If you want to fill the memory allocated with `malloc` with spaces, you should use `memset`, if you want to assign a string literal, you should not use `malloc` at all. What you actually do is overwriting the pointer returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried to adjust the length of 'blank' as I recognised that flaw when I read up on strcat and strncat.  I'll try to implement your suggestions.  Why does your 'blank = malloc...' not have the (char *)?
Does blank[0]=0 store a '0' in the first memory address for blank?  That contradicts the blank = "";?  Hope my questions make sense.

Comment: I did not include the typecast, because it is not needed to cast a `void` pointer to a `char` pointer in C. But it is no error to include it anyway.

Comment: Yes, the `blank[0]=0` sets the first character to `0`. You cannot use `blank=""` there because that would overwrite the pointer you got from `malloc`.

Comment: Excellent, it worked.  Thanks!
Final question/information, the '0' in blank was overwritten by the output of strcat.  Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Yes, `strcat` and `strncat` overwrite the terminating `0` character and set one at the end of the concatenated string.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll scuttle of and read up some more on pointers